# Sort a collection of two integers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sorting, int

I have got a PowerShell script which adds items consisting of two items to a collection

```
$feedList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]

foreach (...) {
    $endpointId = ...
    $messagehandler = ...
    $feedItem = [Int]$endpointId,[Int]$messagehandler
    $feedList.Add($feedItem)
}
$feedList = $feedlist | Sort -Unique
```

Unfortunately this seems to sort alphabetically rather than numerically. eg

```
219 20
221 59
222 59
225 67
240 78
246 90
46 34
47 31
49 96
51 47
52 103
52 113
52 18
52 20
52 26
52 74
52 76
52 81
55 10
58 18
59 64
60 17
61 52
69 63
70 30
75 12
89 14
90 28
93 1
```

Comment: `$feedlist | Sort -unique` -> `$feedlist | Sort {$_ -as [int]} -unique`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work unless I'm not doing it correctly.  if I do $feedlist = $feedlist | Sort {$_ -as [int]} -unique I get just 55 and next line 10. If I use the whole line $feedlist | Sort -unique -> $feedlist | Sort {$_ -as [int]} -unique I get Error Sort-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[] System.Object[] System.Object[]

Comment: I completely agree with @Ansgar answer. As for what you tried: you created an array with a **single** column consisting out of another array with two (integer) items. In other words, your trying to sort array items (not integers)...

Answer (score 2):

Since you define `$feedList` as a generic list of custom objects I'd recommend actually creating custom objects and then sorting them by property.

```
foreach (...) {
    ...
    $feedItem = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'EndpointId'     = [int]$endpointId
        'MessageHandler' = [int]$messagehandler
    }
    $feedList.Add($feedItem)
}
$feedList = $feedList | Sort -Unique EndpointId, MessageHandler
```